# LoadIcon()/LoadImage() fails with error code 0x00000715

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I am trying to load an icon in my Windows taskbar DeskBand  but it always fails with error code 0x00000715(The specified resource type cannot be found in the image file). I have already included the resource.h file and it contains the id for the ICON. Here is the code i use to load the icon.

```
m_hIcon = (HICON)LoadImage(m_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON_1), 
                                  IMAGE_ICON, 32, 32, LR_SHARED);
if (m_hIcon )
{
ATLTRACE(_T("Icon loaded successfully"));
}
else
{

ATLTRACE(_T("Couldnot load icon %x"),GetLastError());
}
```

I have also tried the loading the ICON with LoadIcon() function but it also fails with the same error.

```
LoadIcon(m_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON_1));
```

EDIT:
I used the ATL Project template to create the dll.

Comment: did it make an entry in the resource file(.rc)? I'm unable to recollect how to make entry in the resource file (.rc). The (.rc) resource file will have resource.h include. Try to open that file with editor and see some previous entries if it already has and use that format to make an entry for your image/png file and try it.

Comment: the .rc file has a resource entry `IDI_ICON_1               ICON                    "icon1.ico"`

Comment: may that you are trying to load an icon through loadImage function. use LoadIcon and try it.

Comment: I have tried both..none of them work.

Comment: Give NULL instead of m_hInst and check.

Comment: tried that as well... no luck

Comment: @RCBrand That would lead to a search of the executable file rather than the module that contains the resource. No need for guesswork here.

Comment: oh. okay. Thanks! not so sure about that,.

Comment: @RCBrand Also, `LoadImage` is documented to be able to load icons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error code is [`ERROR_RESOURCE_TYPE_NOT_FOUND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681386.aspx) which is described as so:

> The specified resource type cannot be found in the image file.

That is pretty unequivocal. The module identified by that module handle has no icon resource with that resource name and type. Either you are passing the wrong module handle, or you failed to link the icon resource.

Comment: but i have verified that the icon files are present in the `Resource Files` filter and defined in both resource.h and the .rc file. I think its worth mentioning that the project is compiled as a dll which is then loaded into explorer.exe(DeskBand)

Comment: *Either you are passing the wrong module handle, or you failed to link the icon resource.* Verify that the resources are there using a resource viewer. Use that tool to inspect the DLL. That will allow you to be 100% sure that the resources are there. If they are, and that error is still returned, you are passing the wrong module handle.

Comment: The resources are present in the dll(verified using Resource Viewer). I am using the ATLProject template to create the dll.I have tried using `_AtlBaseModule.GetModuleInstance()` but it didnt work either.

Comment: There is a 3rd error mode: The Icon with the specified ID is linked into the binary as a resource, but of a different type (e.g. a raw binary resource). The error here, however, is likely to be the wrong module handle: Using the [__ImageBase](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/10/25/247180.aspx) pseudo linker variable will always return the correct module handle.

Comment: Instead of using the m_hInst created while registering the window class inside the dll, I had to use _AtlBaseModule.GetResourceInstance() which worked.

Comment: @IInspectable's offering is my preferred option, FWIW

Comment: @thunderbird: Using the `__ImageBase` pseudo linker variable will always point to the starting address in memory to the module, that the expression got compiled into. This is particularly true, if you ship your code as a static library. Getting the MFC/ATL resource management right requires **a lot** of reading, and insight, both from the original author as well as the developer tasked to maintain the code in question. I'd always pick the more obvious solution (i.e. `__ImageBase`).